# How do I properly center align mat-chip-list?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, angular-material

[chips not center aligned in the first card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqHKl.png)

I've got two mat-cards with a mat-chip-list in each card.
When the chip list is 5 or greater the alignment of the chips are to the left.
May I please be advised as to what the issue is?

```
mat-card {
    height: 752px;
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

mat-card-header {
    display: block;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.mat-card-content{
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto; 

}

<div fxLayout="row wrap">
        <div fxFlex="33%">
            <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4">
                <mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-title>
                        <h2>title goes here</h2>
                    </mat-card-title>
                </mat-card-header>
                <img class="imageBorder" src="assets/laptop-code-solid.svg" alt="" />
                <mat-card-content>
                    content here
                </mat-card-content>
                <mat-card-actions fxFlexAlign="center">
                    <mat-chip-list aria-label="Languages">
                        <mat-chip>C#</mat-chip>
                        <mat-chip>.Net</mat-chip>
                        <mat-chip>SQL</mat-chip>
                        <mat-chip>
                            JavaScript
                        </mat-chip>
                        <mat-chip>HTML</mat-chip>
                        <mat-chip>Bootstrap</mat-chip>
                        <mat-chip>CSS</mat-chip>
                      </mat-chip-list>
                </mat-card-actions>
            </mat-card>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add the following style to `<mat-card-action>` tag -

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center; // horizontally centered
```

Because all the chip items belong to parent . Flex works on its direct child items.

Refer to this for better understanding - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

```html
mat-card {
    height: 752px;
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width:300px;
    
}

mat-card-header {
    display: block;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.mat-card-content{
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto; 

}
```

you can use style css with concept flexbox flex-wrap with a certain width. For more detail about flexbox concept and example using you can look:
"https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp"